# Relatively simple SQL query with join refuses to be efficient

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, mariadb

I'm having some problems optimizing a certain query in SQL(using MariaDB), to give you some context: I have a system with "events"(see them as log entries) that can occur on tickets, but also on some other objects besides tickets(which I why I seperated the event and ticket_event tables). I want to get all ticket_events sorted by display_time. The event table has ~20M rows right now.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` text,
  `display_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_for_display_time_and_id` (`id`,`display_time`),
  KEY `index_for_display_time` (`display_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticket_event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ticket_id` (`ticket_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `ticket_event`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ticket_event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `event` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ticket_event_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ticket_id`) REFERENCES `ticket` (`id`);
```

As you see I already played around with some keys(I also made one for (id, ticket_id) that doesn't show up here now since I removed it again) The query I execute:

```
SELECT * FROM ticket_event
INNER JOIN event ON event.id = ticket_event.id
ORDER BY display_time DESC
LIMIT 25
```

That query takes quite a while to execute(~30s if I filter on a specific ticket_id, can't even complete it reliably without filtering on it). If I run an explain on the query it shows it does a filesort + temporary:
[image: EXPLAIN result]
I played around with force index etc. a bit, but that doesn't seem to solve anything or I did it wrong.

Does anyone see what I did wrong or what I can optimize here? I would very much prefer not to make "event" a wide table by adding ticket_id/host_id etc. as columns and just making them NULL if they don't apply.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Extra image of `EXPLAIN` with actual rows in the table:
[image: extra explain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK what if you try to force the index?

```
SELECT * FROM ticket_event
INNER JOIN event 
FORCE INDEX (index_for_display_time) 
ON event.id = ticket_event.id
ORDER BY display_time DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: This solved it, apperantly I was using force index in the wrong way. 0.0025 sec queries for this are totally acceptable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your query selects every column from every row, even if you use a LIMIT. Have you tried to select one specific row by id?

Comment: I tried both having `SELECT event.id` and added a `WHERE ticket_event.ticket_id = xxx`, both give the same result/slowness (obviously it's faster, but still nowhere near acceptable, it's still doing filesort)

Comment: The "problem" seems to occur because of the sorting. Did you look at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html and https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/improvements-to-order-by/?

Comment: Yes, from those documents I kind of thought the key on event.id + event.display_time would make it work. But it didn't

Comment: Can you please try to execute an optimize command:

optimize table event;
optimize table ticket_event;

Comment: Currently not enough space in the temp folder for that, will add comment again when I fix that(might take a bit since I'll have to contact my devops person for that :P). Will optimize ever make it not use filesort though?

Comment: It doesn't have affect on the optimizer but I also had situations where it accelerated the query massively because the command defragments the table. What about your mariadb configuration e.g. cache size etc.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89587/discussion-between-blackflag-and-teuneboon).

Answer (score 0):

```
KEY `index_for_display_time_and_id` (`id`,`display_time`),
```

is useless; DROP it.  It is useless because you are using InnoDB, which stores the data "clustered" on the PK (`id`).

Please change `ticket_event`.`id` to `event_id`.  `id` is confusing because it feels like the PK of the mapping table, which it is.  But wait!  That does not make sense?  There is only one ticket for each event?  Then why does `ticket_event` exist at all?  Why not put `ticket_id` in `event`?

For a many-to-many table, do

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticket_event` (
  `event_id`  int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`, ticket_id),  -- for lookup one direction
  KEY         (`ticket_id`, event_id)   -- for the other direction
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT;
```

Comment: Because ticket_event is just one of the ~10 different event tables. If I add 10 many-to-many tables or 10 columns to the event table it'll become even more confusing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will achieve a better performance by trying this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ticket_event 
INNER JOIN (select * from event ORDER BY display_time DESC limit 25) as b
ON b.id = ticket_event.id;
```

Comment: Problem with this is that if the most recent 25 events aren't all ticket events it won't show 25 events(because the sub query is already limited to 25 results)